# Change date Format in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I want to change the date format in notepad++ to DB visualizer  format

Before

```
30-12-2018
23-12-2018
```

Expected

```
2018-12-30
2018-12-23
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression search and replace to do this:

In "Find what" enter :

```
(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2,4})
```

In "Replace with" enter :

```
\3-\2-\1
```